# How To Make Chat Bot In Batch

Tags: batch-file, chat, bots

I want create a chat bot progrom in batch.

The chat bot responds to different keywords.

For example:
If you said Hi, bot. Then it takes the keyword `"Hi"` and then responds with something like: `Hello, What Is Your Name?`

Here is my code:

```sh
@echo off 
color 0a
title Chat Bot
:chatloop
set /p n=Name:
set /p c=Chat:

If "%c%" Contains "Hi" (   <-- What would be this line of code?        

echo Hi, how are you?
pause
goto chatloop


)
```

Comment: What's your question? Do you want us to code a chat AI for you? Or just a peace of code that responds with "Hello, What Is Your Name?" on typing "Hi"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to make a chat bot that responds to different keywords, @MichaelS

Comment: somebody watched 'halt and catch fire'  :-D ?

Comment: How is this relelated, @npocmaka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for keywords instead of full phrases:

```
@echo off
:loop
set /p input="> "
echo %input%|find /i "hi" >nul && echo Hello.
echo %input%|find /i "your name" >nul && echo My name is Rob. What's yours?
echo %input%|find /i "my name is" >nul && echo That's a nice name.
echo %input%|find /i "wheather" >nul && echo Wonderful. Sun is shining.
echo %input%|find /i "bye" >nul && (echo what a pity. See you! & goto :eof)
REM choose your keywords wisely...
goto :loop
```

Note: this is a very basic "show how". No errorhandling at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
:CHATLOOP
SET /P input=Your message:
IF %input%==Hi ECHO Hello, What Is Your Name?
IF %input%==Something ECHO something else
IF %input%==How are you? ECHO Fine. How are you?
IF %input%==quit GOTO END
GOTO CHATLOOP
:END
PAUSE
```

Comment: I mean't the chat bot responds to different keywords. For example: How are you, bot? Then the bot would detect "how are you" and then respond with something like: Fine. How are you?

Comment: For each keyword add `IF %input%==keyword  ECHO desired answer`. For the given case add the line `IF %input%==How are you? ECHO Fine. How are you?`

Comment: Then you can only chat with one word. I want to chat with multiple words.

Comment: OMG...you can add ANY keyword. If you want 1000 keywords, insert 1000 `IF %input%=keyword ECHO answer` lines. Btw, there is a reason why chat bots aren't written in bat.

Comment: But what would happen if I said "Hi, robot" than "Hi, bot"?

Comment: In this case you have to insert these two lines: `IF %input%==Hi, robot ECHO Hello!` and `IF %input%==Hi, bot ECHO Hi there!`

Comment: Ok. Still not the answer I'm looking for, @MichaelS

Comment: @Nuach: You're actually asking for some kind of grammar / pattern recognition _and_ ask people to write it from scratch without giving it a shot. This is ridiculous to ask on stackoverflow. Since you have absolutely 0 programming experience, you should really follow a few tutorials first.

Comment: Sorry but the answer to your question is: THIS IS TERRIBLE! Don't use BAT for that. Don't use a smartphone to cut bread, don't run with scissors, don't do stupid things.

Comment: A made a chat program in batch before, but I don't know how to make chat bot, @MichaelS

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do it without keywords, only answering on the exact input you can try this code:

```
@echo off
color f0
set T=speak.dat
echo Hinweis: nur kleinbuchstaben verwenden keine satzzeichen
echo beliebige Taste zum starten
pause >nul
:A
title speak2me
set /p ui=
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /b "%ui%:" %T%') do set "out=%%j" >nul
echo %out%
goto :A
```

What you may have seen is, that you need a database (named T=speak.dat) in style:

```
any input:output
```

example of my database:

```
hi:hey
how are you:I am fine, thanks
bye:See you next time
```

When you want to write new sentences type it in the database or use the following batch:

```
@echo off
echo Benutzereingaben immer klein ohne Sonderzeichen etc
pause
echo (BE:BenutzerEingabe,I:Was ich darauf antworte)
:A
set /p BE=BE:  
set /p I=I:  
echo %BE%:%I% >> speak.dat
echo Ok danke,
echo Auf %BE% antworte ich mit %I%
goto :A
```

(if my english isn't the best, please excuse, I am not a native speaker
if you want to have the little text fragments translated use google german>English,thanks :D)

I hope I can help you,
greetings Tim